# Silverlight IGoogle example (Photo linked)

Tags: silverlight, igoogle

Does anyone know which silverlight or third party controls can help me make an igoogle dashboard similar to the one in the photo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfSd7.jpg

- Notice how "Weather", "Date & Time", and "YouTube" all have different sized windows.
- Dragging and rearranging windows is also supported

I've seen plenty of examples of floating windows or docking windows (similar to visual studio docking windows), but that's not what igoogle has or does.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Blacklight controls library in the past to achieve that dashboard like functionality.  Checkout the demo and you should find what you need.

http://blacklight.codeplex.com/

Comment: I considered using this, but the demo doesn't illustrate having multiple sized windows the way igoogle does. Do you know if this is possible with blacklight?

Comment: Right out of the box, I believe the blacklight controls would not support having multiple sized windows.  Although you might be able to play around with different sized grids and cell sizes, to see if that works.  The project is also open source so you can also modify the source to fit your needs.